# cocoapod : Permission denied when pushing repository to trunk

Tags: git, cocoapods

I'm trying to push my cocoapod project to trunk. But every time this occur

```
pod trunk push MyCocoaPod.podspec

Updating spec repo `master` Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance [!] /usr/bin/git fetch
--unshallow

error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

because you don't have enough permissions on the .git/FETCH_HEAD directory, please running the following command:

```
cd `your cocoa pod project file`
sudo  chown -R `courser` .git/
```